# wpf custom title bar does not work but have no exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf

I downloaded the sample code from 
http://www.cnblogs.com/Files/sheva/RibbonStyle2.zip

I added three key files into a new project without changing the files. They are **NativeMethods.cs, OfficeWindow.cs, and Generic.xaml.**
I then use my new WFP form (MainWindow.xaml) to inherit from OfficeWindow.

```
<cc:OfficeWindow 
            x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:RibbonStyle"
            ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</cc:OfficeWindow>
```

and code behind MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using RibbonStyle;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : OfficeWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The design view looks good. It shows ribbon style title bar as expected. However when I run it in the debugger it shows a classic title bar without and exceptions.

Note that if you download the original sample code from 
http://www.cnblogs.com/Files/sheva/RibbonStyle2.zip
and run it directly it works.

Can anyone try my way and tell me what I have missed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i have checked this example ..i think it is working fine here is the screeschot..[image: sceenshot]

if thr is problem in its styling comment below..

Comment: Thank you for checking into this. I really appreciate it. I import three relevant files into another project in VS2012 and it stopped working. the three files are

Comment: OfficeWindow.cs,NativeMethods.cs,Generic.xaml

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: can you guys remove the on hold?